# Find another cosine y(t), whose frequency is as close as possible to that of x(t),

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, continuous-signals, digital

I am going to be straight forward and say this is one of the problem sheets and I am stuck on one of the questions.  I already know the answer as I have been given them but I am trying to work backwards to see how to derive from the answer.  so the question is:

```
 Find another cosine y(t), whose frequency is as close as possible to that of x(t),
 which when sampled with T=1ms yields the same sample values as x(t). 
 Write the equation and sketch y(t) vs. t.
```

where $x(t) = 10\cos(500\pi t)$

here is the answer

[image]

the question is I don't quite understand why $10\cos(1500\pi t)$ would go through those points and not $10\cos(1000\pi t)$.

Comment: Do you already know what aliasing is? If yes, it can be easily explained with that effect. If not, this problem is possibly used to guide you there.

Comment: I do know what aliasing is, however it said to find another cosine wave that passes through those points.  I'm not sure how they got y(t) = 10cos(1500πt).  I think it's my problem for not explaining clearly as I am not very good at explaining things sorry.  What I wanted to know is how do you find another cosine wave other than x(t) that passes through those points.

Comment: Try plotting $10\cos(1000 \pi t)$ and see what happens.